# Flutter filter list

Tags: list, flutter

this is what happening
when i try to get list without filtering it's working good. but when i try to filter list using where condition is not working
this is what happening
when i try to get list without filtering it's working good. but when i try to filter list using where condition is not working
this is what happening
when i try to get list without filtering it's working good. but when i try to filter list using where condition is not working

```
 late String _email = '';
  var _users = [];
  String api =
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilkacase1234/Amore/main/Users.json';
  login() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(api));
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
        setState(() {
          _users = data;
        });
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.showError(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    login();
    super.initState();
  }

  check() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? login = prefs.getString('login');
    if (login != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.id);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _email = val;
                    });
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    hintText: 'Halkan ku qor magalada gurigu ku yaalo',
                    prefixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final currentUser = _users[index];
            if (_users.isEmpty) {
              return Center(child: Text('No data'));
            } else {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 28,
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(currentUser['image'].toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text(currentUser['email'].toString()),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(currentUser['password'].toString()),
                      Text(currentUser['name'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}


late String _email = '';
  var _users = [];
  String api =
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilkacase1234/Amore/main/Users.json';
  login() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(api));
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as List;
      var data1 = data
              .where((el) => el['email']
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .contains(_email.toLowerCase()))
              .toList();
        setState(() {
          _users = data1;
        });
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.showError(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    login();
    super.initState();
  }

  check() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? login = prefs.getString('login');
    if (login != null) {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.id);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Login'),
        elevation: 0,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() {
                      _email = val;
                    });
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    hintText: 'Halkan ku qor magalada gurigu ku yaalo',
                    prefixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    filled: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _users.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final currentUser = _users[index];
            if (_users.isEmpty) {
              return Center(child: Text('No data'));
            } else {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 28,
                    backgroundImage:
                        NetworkImage(currentUser['image'].toString()),
                  ),
                  title: Text(currentUser['email'].toString()),
                  subtitle: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(currentUser['password'].toString()),
                      Text(currentUser['name'].toString()),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
login() async {
try {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(api));
  response.body.forEach(e){
    if(e["email"].toLowerCase() == _email.toLowerCase()){
      _user = json.decode(e)
    }
  }
} catch (e) {
  EasyLoading.showError(e.toString());
}}
```